# On the dicyclic group of order $4n$ and the dihedral group of order $2n$

Tags: group-theory

Let $Q_{4n}$ be the dicyclic group of order $4n, n\geq 2$ and $D_{2n}$ to be the dihedral group of order $2n$. Then prove that

$$\dfrac{Q_{4n}}{Z(Q_{4n})}\cong D_{2n},$$
 Where $Z(G)$ is the center $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following presentation of $Q_{4n}$ :

$$Q_{4n}:=\langle x,y|x^{2n}=y^4=1,x^n=y^2,y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle$$

"Clearly" the center of $Q_{4n}$ will be generated by $x^n=y^2$. Hence this a group of order $2$. Now if I denote $\pi:Q_{4n}\rightarrow Q_{4n}/Z(Q_{4n})=:Q$ then $X:=\pi(x)$ is of order in $Q$ of order $2n$ so the subgroup $H:=\langle X\rangle\triangleleft Q$. Finally $Y:=\pi(y)$ is of order $2$ in $Q$ and not included in $H$ so if $K:=\langle Y\rangle$ then we have :

$$Q=H\rtimes_{\phi} K$$

Is a semi-direct product. Now $\phi(Y)(X)=YXY^{-1}=X^{-1}$ Hence if we change $H$ to the cyclic group of order $n$ and $K$ the cyclic group of order $2$ we have that $\phi(1\text{ mod } 2)(1\text{ mod } n)=-1\text{ mod } n$ Hence we see that :

$$Q\text{ is isomorphic to } \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}\rtimes_{-Id_{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}}}\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} $$

This is the precise definition of the dihedral group of order $2n$.